# Is grass OK instead of hay?

Tags: health, diet, rabbits

My rabbit had dental work yesterday (teeth ground). He is eating greens and a few pellets, but isn't interested in hay. He never loved it, but he did eat some. I know it's important, but is it OK for him to eat grass instead (for short term and long term)? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: In general fresh green gras has more nutrients than hay. After dental work fresh green is easy to eat (better  than "hard" hay).

Answer (score 2):

Yes your bunny can eat grass, it is always good to have a variety of hays as they all contain different levels of nutrients depending on the soil they grow in.

A few ways to entice your bunny to eat more hay.

1) Limit the amount of pellets and fresh they get a day. 1/4 cup of pellets per 6lbs and 2 cups of veggies per 6lbs of ideal body weight.  You may have to adjust the fresh veggies accordingly as sometimes it can give rabbits diarrhea.

2) Have hay available at all times.

3) Try different brands/types of hay as some will be tastier than others. Avoid Alfalfa hay in older buns as it has a lot more protein/calcium than what they need.

4) Mix the hays with foods your rabbit likes.

A few popular hays are timothy, orchard grass, oat and Meadow.